# Custom login page for Twitter using spring social

Tags: spring-boot, twitter, twitter-oauth, spring-social

I'm currently working towards completing university course. One of the task is to create application, which retrieve user data from Twitter APIs and then display data on webpage. To retrieve user data user should first sign in to our app. For make this process easier we are using spring social

**Is it possible to customize login page that when user has to sign in, he WILL BE NOT redirect to Twitter signin page?** So when user provide information like email and password on my webpage, the process of getting twitter access token will be handle in background(in java code).

If it is possible, how to do that? And how the flow of the my program will look like?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No you can not do that. That would be a huge security flaw, people entering their passwords on random websites. That's called a phishing attack

Comment: What have you tried - please provide your code? We would I recommend you check how you could improve your question, here: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask